# IIS Redirecting

Tags: iis

Is there any way I can have all pages in my site go to 1 page? Basically I will have 1 index.html in my site.. I would like it so if the user goes to any wrong link or anything in my site, I want it to go to this page. Can this be accomplished? We are basically putting out site down and have over 1000's of pages in different directories. Just trying to think of an easy way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

You can set that page as your 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Put an **app_offline.htm** page at the root of your site.

Explanation:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx

Comment: That's what Greg was trying to accomplish. His question wasn't clear enough because he mentioned 'wrong link' but when you read it as a whole, you can understand that what he really meant was making all his 1000's of pages to display one page when the site is down.